# using robocopy with C# Foreach.Parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, robocopy

I have information about Source and destination dirs for multiple locations in Datatable.

I am iterating through the datatable using foreach parallel and then two tasks are performed,
Copy files to dest and rename copied file on Dest.

While doing this sometimes i am getting errors like,

**ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Accessing Source Directory The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
,
 

ERROR 32 (0x00000020) Accessing Destination Directory The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

And while renaming i am getting error as 
**Error Renaming file, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**

E.g.

```
   var options = new ParallelOptions()
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
                };
    Parallel.foreach(datatableObj.AsEnumerable(), options, row =>{

    string sourcePath = row.Field<string>("source_path");
    string destPath = row.Field<string>("dest_path");
    string searchPattern = row.Field<string>("Search_pattern");

    List<string> files=Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern);
    string ROBOCOPY_STATIC_ARGUMENTS = @"/MT:32 /BYTES /COPY:DAT /NP /R:3 /W:1";
    foreach(string file in fIles)
    {
          CopyUsingRoboCopy(file,DestPath,ROBOCOPY_STATIC_ARGUMENTS);
          RenameFile(file,NewFileName+datetimewithmilliseconds.ext);
    }

});
```

As 2 threads as executing in parallel manner but single threads execution is sequential i.e. First copy and then renameFiles. So i am not getting why i am getting errors mentioned above.

**Note: Destination paths is same for all**

Comment: Where is `NewFileName` set? It looks like you try to rename every file to the same name as `NewFileName` doesn't seem to change. If it's set in `CopyUsingRoboCopy` then every time one thread changes it the others will also get the change and try to rename it to the same name. In this case `CopyUsingRoboCopy` should return the new file name.

Comment: Each file is renamed to different name as it has  timestamp in it :)

Comment: But the copying is very likely so fast that multiple files would be copied during the same second and thus still get the same name.

Comment: Apologies for  incomplete information. Timestamp is till milliseconds and every file is uqniue.

Comment: Why are you using `Parallel.ForEach` at all? For starters, Robocopy can already execute operations using multiple threads with the `/mt` switch. Second, it runs as a separate process. You could start 100 instances in a loop with `Process.Start` if you want, and just wait for `Process` objects to complete. `Parallel.ForEach` is only meant for data parallelism, and there's no data here

Comment: As for why you're getting file conflicts, it's because you end up trying to read or write the same files. This has nothing to do with `Parallel.ForEach`, nor can it be fixed by locking or anything like that in your code. Perhaps `CopyUsingRoboCopy` *doesn't* wait for the process to complete? Or the source folders contain files with similar names? Perhaps some of those files are open in another process?